# Problem in creating of android vector assets from psd file (created with photoshop)

Tags: android, android-assets

I'm trying to create vector assets from `psd` file I've created in photoshop (it actually contains one layer made from a `png` image, with a transparent background), but all my tries were failed (I have also tried to convert it so `svg` file which didn't help) and I got an empty vector asset.

There is something special that I need to do in my android project/ when I'm saving the `psd` file for it to work?